# How to figure out which rendering is causing "Error serializing .componentProps[] returned from getStaticProps, undefined cannot be serialized as JSON

Tags: nextjs, vercel

I've got a prerendering error that's breaking my builds, and I can't figure out how to track down where in the code the issue is because the error message is so generic when this happens:

> Error: Error serializing
> .componentProps["bdb88b2b-cc25-49a2-8012-85817aacef25"].result.children
> returned from `getStaticProps` in "/[[...path]]".
> Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.

There's obviously null data being passed into a rendering that's unable to handle it, but how can I figure out which rendering is the issue when there's about 40 renderings on the page? The call stack doesn't refer to any specific tsx renderings, and the ID in `.componentProps["bdb88b2b-cc25-49a2-8012-85817aacef25"]` isn't a Sitecore ID so far as I can tell.

```
Call Stack
isSerializable
file:///C:/Dev/Site/src/rendering/node_modules/next/dist/lib/is- serializable-props.js (36:19)
<unknown>
file:///C:/Dev/Site/src/rendering/node_modules/next/dist/lib/is- 
serializable-props.js (43:66)
```

[image]

Comment: I will suggest, check the components which are using the child elements and add the null handling OR remove the rendering one by one from page and identify the component